# SET ASP.NET MVC4 button value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a newbie. 
My problem is that i have a button and i want to set the value by a ASP.NET variable.

`<input type="button" id="mybt" value="<%=Student.Name %>" />`

This code is not working.

---

The code:

```
<%var Products = (IEnumerable<Demo.Models.Product>)ViewBag.Products;%></div>
        <div>
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <%foreach(var product in Products)
          {  %>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:68px;height:20px">
              <%=product.Id %>
          </td>
         <td style="width:120px">
              <%=product.Name%>
          </td>
            <td style="width:120px">
              <%=product.Price %>
          </td>
            <td style="width:120px">    
              <input type="button"   value='<%=product.Id%>' />
            <%} %>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: What's the `Student` object? Is it the model of your view? If yes, then you should set `Model.Name` instead.

Comment: I'm confused.  How does the first code snippet that seems to be referring to a `Student` have anything to do with the second snippet, that of a list of `Products`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of <%=Student.Name %> use this:  @Student.Name

Provided that "Student" is the model name and "Name" is the property you want.

The reason for this is because <%= %> works for aspx but not the razor view engine which is probably what you have chosen for your MVC solution.

Comment: in question @Tien did not mention that he use rezor view engine. probably `Student` is model of view.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it might have something to do with the fact that `<%=Student.Name %>` is valid syntax for ASP MVC 1 & 2.

Comment: In fact, I use aspx view. @ Student.Name (student is an object belong to Student). And I can not use @ Student.Name. It's an error syntax @po10cySA

Comment: @Tien: if it didn't work, then why did you accept this answer?